# Encode the & in header() function

Tags: php

I am doing this redirect:

```
$perf = get_query_var('goperf');
$campaignid = get_option('campaign_id');
$url = 'http://ww.mysite.com?test=1&testtwo=2';
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header('Location: '.$url); 
exit;
```

Should I use:

```
$url = 'http://ww.mysite.com?test=1&testtwo=2';
```

Or should I encode the &? using & instead of &

```
$url = 'http://ww.mysite.com?test=1&amp;esttwo=2';
```

TY

Comment: The first one. Try them both out in your browser, only one of them will pass the get values to your script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the htmlencoded variant **ONLY** if the URL is being inserted into an HTML document.

So if you have:

```
<a href="<?php echo $url;?>">click me!</a>
```

you should use the `&amp;` variant (htmlencoded)

If you're doing:

```
header("Location: " . $url);
```

or anything else that isn't the first case, **don't** htmlencode.

Comment: I am doing this to redirect affiliate links... when I encode, my parameters aren't passed after the redirect... so you are right, I should NOT encode them